# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'receiver' cannot be null

Tags: php, laravel

I have looked at all previous posts about this topic and I can't seem to find what I am doing wrong.

I have a two-way SMS platform which allows me to receive messages from Twilio and then save them in my database.

I had no problem saving the phone numbers and the body of the message, however when I try to save the media and the number of media in the message I get errors.

Full error:
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5B0Bw.jpg)

My reply Twilio code

```
    public function replyTwilio(Request $request)
{
    $number = $request->input('From');
    $to = $request->input('To');
    $body = $request->input('Body');
    $numMedia = $request->input('NumMedia');
    $mediaUrl = '';

    if ($number == '' && $body = '' && $to == '') {
        return 'Invalid Request';
    }

if ($numMedia != 0) {
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $numMedia; $i++) {
        $mediaUrl = $request->input('MediaUrl' + $i) + ',';
    }
}
    $clphone = str_replace(" ", "", $number); #Remove any whitespace
    $clphone = str_replace('+', '', $clphone);

    $msgcount = strlen($body);
    $msgcount = $msgcount / 160;
    $msgcount = ceil($msgcount);

    $get_status = $this->insertSMS($clphone, $msgcount, $body, $to, 1, $mediaUrl, $numMedia);

    if ($get_status) {
        return 'success';
    } else {
        return 'failed';
    }

}
```

InsertSMS():

```
    public function insertSMS($number, $msg_count, $body, $to = '', $gateway = '', $media, $num_media)
{
    $get_info = SMSHistory::where('receiver', 'like', '%' . $number)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();

          if ($get_info) {

        if (strtolower($body) == 'stop'){
            BlackListContact::create([
                'user_id' => $get_info->userid,
                'numbers' => $number
            ]);

            $gateway_info = SMSGateways::find($gateway);
            $this->dispatch(new SendBulkSMS($get_info->userid, $number, $gateway_info, $to, 'You will no longer receive any messages', '1', null));

        }


        if (strtolower($body) == 'start'){
            $contact = BlackListContact::where('numbers',$number)->first();
            if ($contact){
                $contact->delete();
            }
        }

        $status = SMSHistory::create([
            'userid' => $get_info->userid,
            'sender' => $number,
            'receiver' => $to,
            'message' => $body,
            'amount' => $msg_count,
            'status' => 'Success',
            'api_key' => null,
            'use_gateway' => $gateway,
            'send_by' => 'receiver',
            'sms_type' => 'text',
            'media_url' => $media,
            'num_media' => $num_media
        ]);
    } else {

        if (strtolower($body) == 'stop'){
            BlackListContact::create([
                'user_id' => 0,
                'numbers' => $number
            ]);

            $gateway_info = SMSGateways::find($gateway);
            $this->dispatch(new SendBulkSMS(0, $number, $gateway_info, $to, 'You will no longer receive any messages', '1', null));
        }

        $status = SMSHistory::create([
            'userid' => 0,
            'sender' => $number,
            'receiver' => $to,
            'message' => $body,
            'amount' => $msg_count,
            'status' => 'Success',
            'api_key' => null,
            'use_gateway' => $gateway,
            'send_by' => 'receiver',
            'sms_type' => 'text',
            'media_url' => $media,
            'num_media' => $num_media
        ]);
    }

    if ($status) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }


}
```

And the model for SMSHistory

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class SMSHistory extends Model
{
protected $table='sys_sms_history';
protected $fillable=['userid','sender','receiver','message','amount','status','api_key','use_gateway','send_by','sms_type','media_url','num_media'];
}
```

Comment: The `receiver` column has to have a value. Check `To` field has a value or not. If you want the `receiver` column to be empty then make `receiver` column `nullable`.

Comment: I need both of them to have a value. But how do I do this? I keep getting error. @MdMahfuzurRahman

Comment: Please check the error message carefully. The insert query is trying to insert empty value for `sender` and `receiver` columns. The `$number` and `$to` variables are receiving empty value. Please check that.

Comment: @MdMahfuzurRahman yes I know, but shouldn't it display "Invalid Request" instead of the error?

Comment: the value is empty man empty!

Answer (score 0):

If you want `$number`, `$body` and `$to` variables to be required then try like this:

```
if ($number == '' || $body = '' || $to == '') {
    return 'Invalid Request';
}
```

Replace `&&` operator by `||` operator. If any of them is empty it will return `Invalid Request`.

Answer (score 0):

You should add validation before storing it in tables.

Either you can add request validation or check the mandatory fields are set or not.

```
if (empty($number) || empty($body) || empty($to)) {
   abort(412, 'Invalid Request');
}
```